# Could not load file or assembly the page

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, error

We're using In SharePoint 2010 environment. When users click the link, it shows them error:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If it is a custom webpart, check that code builds correctly and that code is correct. Then rebuild and deploy.

If it is a webpart downloaded from somewhere, maybe you have forgotten to add the proper line in the web.config with the correspondening assembly. [Here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/9dbb68e4-cbeb-4d0a-aa0e-413d6afab0fe/how-to-add-a-assembly-reference-in-the-webconfig-?forum=sharepointdevelopmentlegacy) you have how.

Answer (score 1):

Where did the user click the link?

Did you install the digital clock web part in your SharePoint 2010?

Did you download the digital clock through the article below? If so, you could check if the digital clock web part is installed correctly according to the article below.

Free "Digital Clock" SharePoint Web Part.

http://www.amrein.com/apps/page.asp?Q=5729